# use names of items in list of pandas

Tags: python, pandas, save

I have successfully finished data manipulation using pandas (in python). Depending on my starting data set I end up with a series of data frames - let's say for example sampleA, sampleB, and sample C.
I want to automate saving of these datasets (can be a lot of them) with also a unique identifier in the name
so I create a list of pandas, and use a loop to save the data - I cannot though make the loop give a unique name each time - see for example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
sampleA= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4))
sampleB= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4))
sampleC= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4))
allsamples=(sampleA, sampleB, sampleC)
for x in allsamples:
    #name = allsamples[x]
    #x.to_csv(name + '.dat', sep=',', header = False, index = False)
    x.to_csv(x + '.dat', sep=',', header = False, index = False)
```

when I am using the above (with not the commented lines) all data are saved as x.data, and I keep only the latest dataset; if I do the name line, then i get errors
any idea how I can come up with a naming approach so I can save 3 files named sampleA.dat, sampleB.data, and sampleC.dat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use strings, then you can look up the variable of the same name using [vars()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars):

```
allsamples = ('sampleA', 'sampleB', 'sampleC')
for name in allsamples:
    df = vars()[name]
    df.to_csv(name + '.dat', sep=',', header=False, index=False)
```

Without an argument `vars()` is equivalent to `locals()`. It returns a "read-only" `dict` mapping local variable names to their associated values. (The `dict` is "read-only" in the sense that it is mainly useful for looking up the value of local variables. Like any `dict`, it is modifiable, but modifying the `dict` will not modify the variable.)

Comment: thanks - it worked too; my first try failed because I didn't notice that you changed allsamples - but it works too! thanks I now actually prefer this since it is less work to create the list (or tuple)

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that python tuple items have no names. And moreover, `allsamples[x]` is meaningless, you index tuple with a dataframe, what do you expect to get?

One can use a dictionary instead of a tuple for simultanious variables naming and storing:

```
all_samples = {'sampleA':sampleA, 'sampleB':sampleB, 'sampleC':sampleC}
for name, df in all_samples.items():
    df.to_csv('{}.dat'.format(name), sep=',', header = False, index = False)
```